# How to produce big number of stacked divs on one line with a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have 3 nested div sets.  The top div container is gray.  It contains a div which is yellow, and the latter contains 5 colored white divs.

I have a problem with the behavior of CSS overflow AND the virtual line continuity of consecutive divs (display: inline).

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
I wish to have the nested white divs kept in one line (for any amount of white divs) and a scroll bar only for an horizontal navigation when reaching the maximum width of the yellow box viewpoint (or any viewpoint).  Instead I end up with my white blocks changing line when reaching the yellow box width limit.  Is there a way to do this in a simple manner, without a javascript help ?

Please, any help will be appreciated ?

Thanks in advance.

Code is following:

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Playground</title>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
   div#mysupracontainer {
     position: absolute;
 border:3px solid #000;
     background-color: gray;
 left:250px;
     width: 700px; 
 height: 500px;
     overflow-x: auto;
   }
   div#panels {
     position: absolute;
 border:3px solid #000;
     background-color: yellow;
 left:10px;
 width: auto;
 height: 350px;
     border-style:dotted;
 overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   .panelslide {
     display:inline;
 float: left;
 border:3px solid #000;
 position: relative;
     background-color: white;
 width: 150px;
 height: 280px;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mysupracontainer" ><p>container</p>
     <div id="panels" ><p>panels</p>
        <div class="panelslide">panelslide-1</div>
        <div class="panelslide">panelslide-2</div>
        <div class="panelslide">panelslide-3</div>
        <div class="panelslide">panelslide-4</div>
        <div class="panelslide">panelslide-5</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:

```
div#panels {
    white-space: nowrap;
)
```

and remove `float: left;` from `.panelslide` - then change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`, it should look like this:

```
.panelslide {
     display:inline-block;
     border:3px solid #000;
     position: relative;
     background-color: white;
     width: 150px;
     height: 280px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aMPxc/

Comment: This works fine.  Excellent and quick answer, now I will analyse why this works. Regards.

Comment: It does work fine on Firefox-12, Chrome-19, ... but not very well on IE v8.  Is there a way to correct the behavior for IEs ?

Comment: not sure what's the problem, as I can't test this on IE8 right now :( inline-block is well supported by IE8 - possibly it has to do with something else?

Comment: I also tried the trick proposed by Denis R. Jacobs: `#hidcontainer { overflow: hidden;} * html #hidcontainer { height: 0;}` without success.  IE 8 still do not respect the inline-block rule ?

Comment: It seems to be because the html header is not precisely declared, the browsers interpret without any standard, as there implementation decides.

Comment: that could be a good reason. Always declare a proper doctype. The html5 one will do in most cases: <!doctype html> - if there is no doctype or is not well formed, browsers (especially IE) may render the page in quirks mode rather than standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand properly, but if you are trying to get the inner (white) div's to come in one line, and add a horizontal scroll, instead of them coming downwards, this is a solution :

I added the following css :

```
   div#panels {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      height:286px;
      white-space:nowrap;
   }
   .panelslide {
      display:inline-block;
      height: 280px;
   }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bHKe/) is a sample.

Comment: I guess the keys element here were 'white-space:nowrap' and display settings.  Thanks.  Your comment works too.